# javascript alert message with data retrieval from database not working

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I am trying to show an alert message after the successful booking of a vehicle along with the booking id but its not working. The alert message is not showing after making a booking.

```
 out.println("<html>");
 out.println("<head>");
 out.println("<script>");
 out.println("<alert('Booking Added Successfully.\nYour Booking Reference Number Is" + booking.getBookingID() + "')>");
 out.println("</script>");
 out.println("<META HTTP-EQUIV= Refresh CONTENT=0;URL=BookNewVehicle.jsp>");
 out.println("</head>");
 out.println("</html>");
```

Comment: Remove `<` & `>` from `alert(...)`.

Comment: you should not use < with alert remove < and >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added brakets `<>` inside alert:

```
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<head>");
out.println("<script>");
out.println("alert('Booking Added Successfully.\nYour Booking Reference Number Is" + booking.getBookingID() + "')"); //You should remove the brackets
out.println("</script>");
out.println("<META HTTP-EQUIV= Refresh CONTENT=0;URL=BookNewVehicle.jsp>");
out.println("</head>");
out.println("</html>");
```